# Unable to create a back button in the navigation bar when creating a modal view from a table cell with a search bar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I'm creating a dictionary app.  It's fundamentally a tab bar application, with one tab used for dictionary look-up, and the other tabs used for grammar pages etc.

The dictionary look-up tab has a UISearchBar on top with a UITableView underneath, showing results as the user types in the search term.

When the user clicks on a line in the results, I want to open up a detailed view showing the full dictionary entry.  My understanding is that it would be best if this had a navigation bar on top with a back button to return to the search.

I've created a new view controller for this, and I've put a navigation bar and a text view into the nib file.  However, I cannot make the 'back' button appear in Interface Builder, and it doesn't happen automatically later, either.

To make the new view appear, I use the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    dictEntryViewController *entryView = [[dictEntryViewController alloc]
       initWithNibName:@"dictEntryViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:entryView animated:YES];
}
```

This new view slides in beautifully, but the navigation bar has not got a back button.  As a temporary solution, I've created a normal button in the new view that basically does this:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

... and this works well, but I think it would feel more natural to use the navigation bar for navigation.

I have a feeling my problem is that back buttons only appear when you push a new view onto an existing one where both views share a navigation controller.  However, I cannot put add a navigation bar to my search view, because that part of the screen is already taken up by the search bar.

Possibly I shouldn't use a modal view controller for this, but it seems to work well, and when I tried some alternatives (e.g., pushViewController), it didn't make the back button appear, either.

I would appreciate your help in this matter.  I've been searching for a solution for a long time now, but most solutions seem to involve adding a navigation bar on top of the table view, which I cannot do in this case.

Comment: Did either of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

To get the back button, you'll need to use a `UINavigationController`, or alternatively create your own button graphics. However, I'd suggest you [look at the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for `UISearchDisplayController`, and use this in conjunction with a `UINavigationController`.

With a `UISearchDisplayController`, when you tap in the search bar, it moves out of the way, over the top of the nav bar. Then when you select a row and push your detail view controller onto the nav stack, the view controller will slide in with a back button.

There's a little bit of work getting the `UISearchDisplayController` up and running, but the end result is (IMO) worth it.

You should be able to set this up in IB. In your main NIB drag in a `UINavigationController`, and set it's root view controller to be your list view controller. In the NIB for the list view controller (which is probably a sub class of `UITableViewController`), drag in a **Search Bar and Search Display Controller** on top of the table view, and hook it all up. You'll have to write the code for filtering your result set, but I'm guessing you've done that already.

Comment: Thanks.  I followed your link, but I'm not entirely clear how I would combine the UISearchDisplayController with a UINavigationController.  Would I create only the UINavigationController in Interface Builder, and then create the UISearchDisplayController programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already implemented the Navigation Controller in your application & able to navigate to the next screen ....then its quite tricky.

Are you sure,you have set the Navigation bar Title ,if not then:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.title =@"App Name";
}
```

Now,the **tricky part, just set the Navigation Bar title to Back** & here you will get the Back Button in next View.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    dictEntryViewController *entryView = [[dictEntryViewController alloc]
       initWithNibName:@"dictEntryViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.title =@"Back";

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:entryView animated:YES];
    [entryView release];
}
```

Both the Navigation Controller & PresentModalView Controller works in different ways, your thinking is on right track.If it's navigation, you could use stack & maintain the navigation within application whereas for PresentModalView it starts from scratch,just like a new view & you could implement the NavigationController within same.